# AngularJS handling $http Error/Success in Smart Way

Tags: angularjs

Currently my snippet works like when an Error occurs, it through a message and disappear after a few second, i did it with `$timeout` and even if success response, a success message appear and disappear after a few second. but for some reasons, i dont need now like this.

here you go for my current snippet:

```
$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel)
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.successCallBack = 'You have successfully saved your contact';
            $scope.formModel = {};
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.successCallBack = '';
            }, 6000);
        }, function(response){
            // Showing user exactly what error occurs
            var errorData = response.data
            $scope.errorCallBack = Object.values(errorData)[0][0];
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.errorCallBack = '';
            }, 3000);
        });
```

in above snippet, if i wouldn't use `$timeout` then success and error are would exist together.

**for example: A user submit error data and he got error message and after he submit right data and got a success message, on that time success and  error message are exist together on screen, this weired**

I want something like, When success message appear, it should exist on the screen and if later again an error message occurrs, the success message should disappear and appear error message.

**Optional:**

Here you go to see how used in templates:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" ng-if="successCallBack">
  <p> {{ successCallBack }} </p>
  <strong>UserID :</strong>{{ userid }} <br>
  <strong> Name :</strong>{{ name }} <br>
  <strong> Email :</strong>{{ email }} <br>
  <strong> Phone :</strong>{{ phone }} <br>
  <a href="#!/crud" class="btn btn-primary">Show Me All Contacts</a>
</div> <!--sucess div ended-->

<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="errorCallBack"> <!--( Error div start )this div appear if any error occured during request-->
  <p>Oops! You can't save this contact !</p>
  <p> Cause,  {{ errorCallBack }} </p>
  <strong>UserID :</strong>{{ userid }} <br>
  <strong> Name :</strong>{{ name }} <br>
  <strong> Email :</strong>{{ email }} <br>
  <strong> Phone :</strong>{{ phone }} <br>
</div> <!--error div ended-->
```

Hope you got this issue:

Comment: add this `$scope.errorCallBack = '';` in success callback and `$scope.successCallBack = '';` in error callback

Comment: it will return a blank message for both success and error case, i dont want this

Comment: it is better to use a boolean than strings to check if action succeeded

Comment: How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i wouldn't use `$timeout` then success and error are would exist together.

The response and rejection handlers can call a common function

```
$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel)
  .then(function(response) {
    displayMessage("success",response);
    return response;
}, function(response){
    displayMessage("error",response);
    throw response;
});
```

Then put common code in the common function:

```
var timeoutId;
function displayMessage(type,response) {
    var success = (type == "success");
    $scope.messageClass = success ? "alert-success" : "alert-danger";
    var messageDuration = success ? 6000 : 3000;


    if (success) {
        $scope.messageText = "Contact successfully saved.";
    } else if (response.status == 500) { 
        $scope.messageTest = "Oops, Internal Server Error";
    } else {
        $scope.messageText = "Oops, YOU DID SOMETHING WRONG!!!!";
    };

    //cancel previous timeout
    timeoutId && $timeout.cancel(timeoutId);

    timeoutId = $timeout(function() {
        $scope.messageText = "";
    }, messageDuration);
}
```

The template can be simplified:

```
<div class="alert" ng-class="messageClass" ng-show="messageText">
  <p> {{ messageText }} </p>
  <strong>UserID :</strong>{{ userid }} <br>
  <strong> Name :</strong>{{ name }} <br>
  <strong> Email :</strong>{{ email }} <br>
  <strong> Phone :</strong>{{ phone }} <br>
  <a href="#!/crud" class="btn btn-primary">Show Me All Contacts</a>
</div>
```