# AngularJS trouble in giving feedback to user

Tags: angularjs

I have a form, when a user submit something successfully, they get a success message ! and if the same user submit wrongly, they get error message.

But the problem is: When user get Success message, it always exist on the screen even if he get error message later. i mean, in the same time, it show error and success message together.

I want when success message appear, error message should disappear.

this is my snippet:

```
$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel)
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.successCallBack = 'You have successfully saved your contact';
        }, function(response){
            $scope.errorCallBack = 'an error occured'
        });
```

i hope you got my issues:

here you go to see how i use this message on templates:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" ng-if="successCallBack">
  <p> {{ successCallBack }} </p>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="errorCallBack">
  <p>  {{ errorCallBack }} </p>

</div>
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: The question looks alot like [AngularJS handling $http Error/Success in Smart Way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56276940/5535245) form [@dudd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11522766/dudd). Are you two in the same class or company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need one boolean and one string for the message:

```
$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel)
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.saveSuccess = true;
        $scope.message = 'You have successfully saved your contact';
    }, function(response){
        $scope.saveSuccess = false;
        $scope.message = 'an error occured';
    });
```

in template you can use ng-if:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" ng-if="saveSuccess">
  <p> {{ message}} </p>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="!saveSuccess">
  <p>  {{ message}} </p>

</div>
```

or you can use ng-class simply like that:

```
<div ng-if="formSubmitted" class="alert" ng-class="{ 'alert-success': saveSuccess, 'alert-danger': !saveSuccess }">
  <p> {{ message}} </p>
</div>
```

Edit: you will need another boolean probably in order to know when the form submitted to show success or error messages, something like formSubmitted e.g.

Comment: Thanks, You made my day to fix this